# jQuery function only being run once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the [Moments.js](http://momentjs.com/) library I'm attempting to grab the value of the datetime attribute from every time tag and output the time using natural language.

Given this:

```
<time datetime="2014-06-27"></time>
```

The Results would be:

```
<time datetime="2014-06-11">17 hours ago</time>
```

Using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var time = $('time'),
        date = moment(time.attr('datetime')),
        update = function(){
                   time.html(date.fromNow());
                 };

    update();
});
```

It works, but only for the first time element. All the additional time elements are also saying "17 hours ago".

It's my guess that the function is only being run once on the first instance of time.

How can I make sure it's being run for each, and doing so efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through all the time tags. Right now you are only applying it to the first instance of `<time>`. Use jQuery [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var time = $('time');

    time.each(function() {
        date = moment($(this).attr('datetime'));
        $(this).html(date.fromNow());
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b7X8D/)**

Comment: Thanks, makes sense that I'd have to do that. If I copy and paste your code example it doesn't work for me, but I'll play around with it.

Comment: @rick see edit; I made a couple of syntax errors and I added in a demo link.

Comment: Sick! Works flawlessly. Thanks bud!